# Should I use in or not in to optimise my Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, amazon-redshift

I've a list of 85 values, and I want to limit my query to only use 10 of them.

Is it more efficient to use NOT IN or IN  in the where clause. The exclusion list will not change, but the list of values to include will change, so I would prefer to use NOT IN, but want to ensure I don't make the query very slow if I do that.

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on the actual query, data and many other things.

Comment: this really wont affect your query in redshift  but why not try it? also consider code maintenance and consider which is likely to change more often (use the other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly for the sake of code maintainability it's better to use Not IN or you will have to keep updating code every time you update the inclusion list if you use the IN method.

The actual performance depends on the query, the data being queried and other parameters and a generally acceptable answer to performance questions is to profile your query by running it multiple times and timing them to check performance.

Comment: very good second point - it is important that for redshift you ignore the first run of a query as redshift is "compiling" the first time you run